# how to change gender factor into an numerical coding in r

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I have a factor of males and females say c("male", "female","female")
and I want to create a vector of c(0,1,1)
How can i change that in r?

Comment: you could try as.numeric()

Comment: @Vincent `as.numeric(c("male", "female","female"))` gives a serie of NA. As it should. If they were factors it would transform to c(2,1,1).

Answer (score 7):

With boolean :

```
a <- c("male", "female","female")
(a=="female")*1
```

hth

Comment: I just saw that someone downvoted you, so I now feel the need to say that i upvoted this answer: it may not be the cleanest and most logical way of doing it but it's by far the shortest.

Comment: well, i wonder why someone downvoted this answer. Could this person tell me why, because i can't see the reason.

Comment: That may not be the reason but I saw your answer in the "Low Quality" review queue earlier (the algorithm probably picked it because of its short length): maybe one of the reviewer who didn't know R believed it to be wrong.

Comment: @droopy, I was the downvoter. It was a mistake - Believe me or not, I was suppose to _upvote_ you. I am terribly sorry. I don't know what happened. I have no excuse whatsoever. When I now try to reverse my stupid, stupid vote it is not possible ("vote is looked in unless this answer is edited")... So if you please could make a tiny 'cosmetical' edit or something, and I will try again. Please ping me when it is done. Again, I apologize for my mistake. Really, really embarrasing. It is really a super clean answer that I was suppose to _upvote_! Cheers.

Comment: I just took the liberty to edit "with" to "With", and that was all that was needed for me to be able to upvote you. Well, well, again sorry for the inconvenience. I ping @plannapus as well just to announce my mistake (and correction). Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik Thank you for all these efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most straight-forward way, but I would first change it to a factor, and then, if needed to an integer:

```
a <- c("male", "female","female")
a <- factor(a, levels=c("male","female"), labels=c(0,1))
a
[1] 0 1 1
Levels: 0 1

as.integer(as.character(a)) #Need to be first transformed to a character 
[1] 0 1 1                   #and then to an integer
```